# ASP.NET MVC Logout with Form Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I have a `Logout action` on a controller as so:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session["UserCredential"] = null;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

This working in google chrome browser. but when I am using my web application with firefox browser (latest version) after login and logout from first time. and when I am doing login again to application and pressing on logout button, I am not able to logout from web application. `Request.IsAuthenticated` is returning me true value.

**For Login I used following action:**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Login(string userName, string password)
        {

            User oUser = oRepository.GetUser(userName,password); 
            Session["UserCredential"] = oUser;


            if (oUser != null)
            {
                if (oUser.IsVerified)
                {
                    string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;    
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
                    return Json(new { res = 1, RedirectUrl = Url.Action("Index", "Home") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                else
                {
                    return Json(new { res = 0, RedirectUrl = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }

            return Json(new { res = -1, RedirectUrl = "" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Anyone have idea what i have to do to solve my problem with firefox browser.

Comment: any errors in browser console?

Comment: no. actually on logout button press it's calling index action of Home controller.

Comment: then you solved your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% certain but you could try this.

I've observed that the way `FormsAuthentication` is implemented in ASP.NET, the `SignOut` method does not clear the `ASPXAUTH` cookie. So, on sign-out, what I usually do is, I clear all the cookies in the response myself manually.

You might try doing that. At the very least, in your case, you should clear 2 cookies:

1) The **FormsAuth** cookie. You can get the name of the cookie by accessing a `CookieName` (or some such) static field of the `FormsAuthentication` class.

2) The ASP.NET session cookie. Check the cookie names in the **Immediate Window** (print the `Cookies` collection).

To clear the cookies, just add new cookies to the response object's cookie collection with the same names as the older cookies and then set their expiry date to a date in the past.

Comment: Thanks @Water Cooler v2 for your help. your answer worked for me to solve my problem.